Springboot Email failing for Office365 SMTP account
I am using one of my email(office385) account created from my Godaddy domain. I am trying to send email from a springboot microservice using SMTP. I've enabled SMTP authentication in Godaddy email profile.
private static void godaddy(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender) {
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.office365.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername("my-name@my-business.co.uk");
        mailSender.setPassword("my-password");

        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");

        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
    }```
I am able to pass authentication but after that failiing with following error.


STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO 192.168.1.72
250-LO4P265CA0073.outlook.office365.com Hello [86.145.143.97]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.office365.com, user=my-name@my-business.co.uk, password=
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<my_laptop@[192.168.1.72]>
501 5.1.7 Invalid address
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 501, with response: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

Note: The email address is valid I can send/receive emails in outlook client. 

